# Redirecting Login in button

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, authentication

As I login (enter -- email and enter-- password) I would like to click on the  login button to redirect to anther MVC asp.net page.
How would I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You need handle in action post using `Redirect(redirectpage)` like this

```
public ActionResult Login(LoginModel model)
        {
             // handle logic here
             string redirectpage = "/home";

            return Redirect(redirectpage);
        }
```

You can follow this link for creating Login page 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/security/create-an-aspnet-mvc-5-web-app-with-email-confirmation-and-password-reset

Answer (score 0):

try this code for redirecting to another page

```
Public ActionResult Login(ModelName Objects)
  {
   //your code;
    return RedirectToAction("ActionName", "ControllerName");      
  }
```